# Pasar formato del HTML de pc a celular

Tags: html, css

¿Que tal? como les va

Estoy preparando la mismisima pagina ToDo List, simple, nada complicado, pero al pasar de formato pc a celular, osea el ancho de computadora al ancho del celular, se me generan nuevas lineas cuando me gustaria que este en una misma. ¿Alguna recomendacion de como hacerlo?

A continuacion el codigo:

```html
<section>
  <div class="container-fluid text-center caja">
    <div class="row encabezado">

<!-----Lineas que se me generan hacia abajo y que esten el la misma fila---->

      <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3">
        <div class="actividad">
          <p>Estado act.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-6">
        <div class="actividad">
          <p>Actividad</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-3" id="borrar">
        <div class="actividad" >
          <p>Borrar</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div id="tareas">
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

PD: Por las dudas no borro lo anterior en caso de que se encuentre algo que no este bien

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Y tú css? En tu hoja de estilos debe estar la media query para teléfonos. Hay debe estar el problema. Pero edita tu pregunta y agrega todo el código relacionado

Comment: Tu código parece contener clases de bootstrap. ¿Acaso estás importando correctamente la biblioteca?

Comment: Termine borrando las palabras cuando se pasa a un dispositivo mas pequeño.
Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El modelo de grilla de Bootstrap empieza con pantallas pequeñas y va agregando modificadores según "crece/aumenta" el ancho del dispositivo.

En total son 12 unidades por línea, así que poniendo `col-3` + `col-6` + `col-3` = 12 se va a mantener esa proporcion de columnas en todas las resoluciones. sm = small, md = medium...

Los modificadores `col-sm-*` `col-md-*` etc.. van reemplazando las proporciones segun aumenta el ancho disponible / tamaño de pantalla / viewport / ventana.

Podes consultar los brakpoints ( a que cantidad de pixels cambian ) en la documentación.

Hay variaciones entre las diferentes versiones debido a como ha ido cambiando el tamaño de los dispositivos, por ejemplo lo que se considera pantalla extra pequeña `col-xs-` pantalla pequeña `col-sm-` pantalla mediana `col-md-`, etcétera.

[v3](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid-options)

[v4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#grid-options)

En el siguiente ejemplo, fijate como responde quitando los modificadores de "pantallas no pequeñas" ( primera section vs segunda section )

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-BBtl+eGJRgqQAUMxJ7pMwbEyER4l1g+O15P+16Ep7Q9Q+zqX6gSbd85u4mG4QzX+" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<section>
  <div class="container-fluid text-center caja">
    <div class="row encabezado">

<!-----Lineas que se me generan hacia abajo y que esten el la misma fila---->

      <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3">
        <div class="actividad">
          <p>Estado act.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-6">
        <div class="actividad">
          <p>Actividad</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-3" id="borrar">
        <div class="actividad" >
          <p>Borrar</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div id="tareas">
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<hr />

<section>
  <div class="container-fluid text-center caja">
    <div class="row encabezado">

      <div class="col-3">
        <div class="actividad">
          <p>Estado act.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-6">
        <div class="actividad">
          <p>Actividad</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-3" id="borrar">
        <div class="actividad" >
          <p>Borrar</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div id="tareas">
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```